# Get text inside a span html beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this structure:

```
<span class="_1p7iugi">
<span class="_krjbj">Price:</span>$39</span>
```

and I want to get only the $39, but when I do this code:

```
def getListingPrice2(listing):
    return listing.find("span", {"class":"_1p7iugi"}).text
```

It returns me:

```
Price: $39
```

How can I get only the part I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
mainSoup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
<span class="_1p7iugi">
<span class="_krjbj">Price:</span>$39</span>
</html>
""")

external_span = mainSoup.find('span')
print("1 HTML:", external_span)
print("1 TEXT:", external_span.text.strip())

unwanted = external_span.find('span')
unwanted.extract()
print("2 HTML:", external_span)
print("2 TEXT:", external_span.text.strip())
```

will get you

```
1 HTML: <span class="_1p7iugi">
<span class="_krjbj">Price:</span>$39</span>
1 TEXT: Price:$39
2 HTML: <span class="_1p7iugi">
$39</span>
2 TEXT: $39
```

so

```
def getListingPrice2(listing):
    outer = listing.find("span", {"class":"_1p7iugi"})
    unwanted = outer.find('span')
    unwanted.extract()
    return outer.text.strip()
```

will get you

`$39`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to extract price value use `element.contents[-1]`

```
html='''<span class="_1p7iugi">
<span class="_krjbj">Price:</span>$39</span>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('span',class_='_1p7iugi').contents[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The span class _1p7iugi contains both the Price and $39.
To get what you want, change the html code as follows.

```
<span class="_1p7iugi">Price:</span>
<span class="_krjbj">$39</span>
```